# Get the first and the last time for every day in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a datetime field *created_at*. I want to find out the first time and the last time for every day.

this is working for finding all days:

```
SELECT date(created_at) from foo where person_id=46 group by date(created_at);
```

and this is also working for finding the first and the last time for one day.

```
SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) from foo where person_id=46 and created_at::date = '2015-09-07';
```

my problem is to combine them. I was thinking about using a subquery but it only return one result.

```
SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) 
FROM foo 
WHERE person_id=46 
AND created_at::date IN (
SELECT date(created_at) 
FROM foo 
WHERE person_id=46 
GROUP BY date(created_at));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it for you:

`SELECT DATE(created_at), min(created_at), max(created_at)
FROM foo
WHERE person_id=46
GROUP BY DATE(created_at);`